# Orientation using InvalidateArrange UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

In the Microsoft documentation I found the following:

> Controls that maintain their own orientation property might call
>   [InvalidateArrange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

How do I implement this in my code so that the page or frame does not change its orientation?

Already grateful for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InvalidateArrange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx) method can only be used for updating the layout of the `UIElement` which has their own orientation property, for example [StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.aspx).

> How do I implement this in my code so that the page or frame does not change its orientation?

So, this method is not related to your problem, I think what you need is to forbidden your layout to update from landscape mode or portrait mode?

To do this, you can open up your manifest file and check the `Supported rotations` for example just enable the `Landscape layout`:

[image]

By default they are unchecked so can your page or frame update its layout to adjust to the window. Or you can refer to this thread: [How to enable only landscape mode in a UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608248/how-to-enable-only-landscape-mode-in-a-uwp-app/38627300#38627300) The Api in the question can also be used.