# UWP: block application's orientation to landscape

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

Is it possible to block the application's orientation to landscape?
I found a solution but it blocks the orientation for the whole device(running the app on a microsoft surface).

I am not 100% how this works for UWP apps.

Comment: [InitialRotationPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-initialrotationpreference)

Comment: i have set that option. but the application still rotates

Comment: @mbob Can you attach the code you tried?

Comment: `<uap:InitialRotationPreference>` 
`<uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />` 
`<uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />`
`</uap:InitialRotationPreference>`

Comment: @mbob Try `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable only landscape mode in a UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608248/how-to-enable-only-landscape-mode-in-a-uwp-app)

Comment: @VijayNirmal same. The application still rotates.

Answer (score 0):

There is not inbox API for UWP app, if you don't need to publish this app to Microsoft Store, you can check the solution in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608248/how-to-enable-only-landscape-mode-in-a-uwp-app) referenced by Justion XL.

If this is an app need be published to Store, please submit a **feature request** in our [Feedback Hub app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n).